# TypeError: Cannot handle this data type trying to get binarized image from numpy

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I have numpy array with shape 101*101 with probabilities from 0 to 1 and I can plot numpy as image this way:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
im = Image.fromarray(255*(preds1[1])) 
plt.imshow(im)
```

[image]

Now I want now binarize image by some threshold this way:

```
im = Image.fromarray(255*(preds1[1] > threshold_best)) 

Going to return this error:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)
   2459             typekey = (1, 1) + shape[2:], arr['typestr']
-> 2460             mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
   2461         except KeyError:

KeyError: ((1, 1), '<i8')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-aea94c7b1043> in <module>()
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import matplotlib.image as mpimg
----> 4 im = Image.fromarray(255*(preds1[1] > threshold_best))
      5 plt.imshow(im)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)
   2461         except KeyError:
   2462             # print(typekey)
-> 2463             raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
   2464     else:
   2465         rawmode = mode

TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

But why?

```
preds1[1].shape, 1*(preds1[1] > 0.4).shape
(101, 101), (101, 101)

type(preds1[1]), type(1*(preds1[1] > threshold_best))
(numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray)
```